# How do I display a JS value in the <option value="url here & js here">

Tags: javascript

How can I use document.write to display a value from the drop down menu in

```
<option value="jmp.php?type=auto&rate=<script>document.write(rate)</script>">Auto Insurance</option>
```

Is this even possible? How can I accomplish this goal? On the next page I need to _GET the 'rate' and I cannot figure out how to pass it into the value.

When the forms submitted this code is used to send the user to the URL in the value=""

```
var goBtn = document.getElementById("search");
var menu = document.getElementById("s1");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
  window.location = menu.value;
}
```

Here is the HTML I am working with.

```
<script>
    function getRate() {
      var rate = document.getElementById("s2").value;
    </script>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="subscribe-block">
        <div class="row">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="subscribeForm">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <fieldset style="margin-top: -1.1em">
                <div style="color: #fff;">Insurance Plan</div>
                <select id="s1" class="form-control input-lg">
                  <option value="jmp.php?type=auto&rate=<script>document.write(rate)</script>">Auto Insurance</option>
                  <option value="jmp.php?type=health&rate=<script>document.write(rate)</script>">Health Insurance</option>
                </select>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
              <fieldset style="margin-top: -1.1em">
                <div style="color: #fff;">Estimated Current Payment</div>
                <select name="s2" id="s2" class="form-control input-lg">
                  <option>$5</option>
                  <option>$10</option>
                  <option>$20</option>
                  <option>$30</option>
                  <option>$40</option>
                  <option>$50</option>
                  <option>$60</option>
                  <option>$70</option>
                  <option>$80</option>
                  <option>$90</option>
                  <option>$100</option>
                  <option>$110</option>
                  <option>$120+</option>
                </select>
              </fieldset>
            </div>      
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <input style="color: #fff;" id="search" placeholder="Continue >>" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
   var goBtn = document.getElementById("search");
   var menu = document.getElementById("s1");
   var myObject = {
       "value1": "jmp.php?type=auto&rate=<script>document.write(rate)<\/script>",
       "value2": "jmp.php?type=health&rate=<script>document.write(rate)<\/script>"
   }
   goBtn.onclick = function() {
   window.location = myObject[menu.value];
   }
</script>

<select id="s1" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="value1">Auto Insurance</option>
    <option value="value2">Health Insurance</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the trick. I ended up using $_POST on the action url and set the values to 'health' and 'auto' on the form instead of urls. On the action url page I setup a simple if statement based on the $_POST and then just sent them to a URL with a php header.